# Serialization issue if the parent does not have a no-arg constructor

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying my best to understand this concept. But I am not able to figure out this thing:

If the parent has no no-arg constructor and also the parent does not implement Serializable interface how can a serialize a child class?

Parent.java

```
public class Parent {
    private String parentString;
    public Parent(String parentString) {
        this.parentString = parentString;
        parentString = "Parent";
    }
    public String getParentString(){
        return parentString;
    }
}
```

Child.java

```
public class Child extends Parent implements Serializable{
    private String childString;
    public Child(String childString) {
        super(childString);
        this.childString = childString;
    }
    public String getChildString(){
        return childString;
    }
}
```

TestSerialization.java

```
public class TestSerialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    Child child = new Child("Child");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.ser"));
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(child);
    oos.close();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("file.ser"));
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object obj = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();

    Child castChild = (Child) obj;

    System.out.println(castChild.getParentString());
    System.out.println(castChild.getChildString());


}

}
```

It gives me an Exception while reading the object, saying `java.io.InvalidClassException: test.Child; no valid constructor`. How can a serialize such objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly serialize an object if one of its superclasses is not `Serializable` and has no no-arg constructor. From the documentation:

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields. **The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state.** It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.

(emphasis mine)

If you can modify the parent class, then you should simply add the appropriate no-arg constructor and/or have it implement `Serializable` as appropriate.

If you cannot modify the parent class, then you may want to consider serializing a proxy class instead. You can implement the method

```
Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

in your `Child` to return a proxy object (which will be serialized instead of the `Child` instance), and implement

```
Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

in the proxy class to return an equivalent `Child` instance.

Answer (score 0):

From the Serialization FAQ [If class A does not implement Serializable but a subclass B implements Serializable, will the fields of class A be serialized when B is serialized?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/serializationfaq-jsp-136699.html#serialsuper) :

> Only the fields of Serializable objects are written out and restored. The object may be restored only if it has a no-arg constructor that will initialize the fields of non-serializable supertypes. If the subclass has access to the state of the superclass it can implement writeObject and readObject to save and restore that state.

So you need to provide no-arg constructors and optionally `writeObject` and `readObject` in Child.

Answer (score -2):

You really need a default constructor in both classes. Furthermore you have to make the class Parent Serializable.

Another advice: Please take a look at the constructor of Parent. There you reassign the parameter. this will have no effect.

Comment: You don't need a default constructor in the Serializable class.